How to run wp_remote_get() for SPA page?
I'm trying to use wp_remote_get() to grab some SPA page on Angular or other SPA. For exapmple
$url= 'https://angular.dev/';
$args = array(
            'sslverify' => true,
            'headers' => array(
                'User-Agent' => 'Your Custom User Agent',
            ),
            'timeout' => 45,
        );

        $html = wp_remote_get($url, $args);

But I didn't get the right (full) content. Can you recommend which arguments (or other function) to use for grabbing the full HTML content after the DOM has been created?
Is it possible to get the application content after the DOM is created?

The problem with SPAs is a lot of the content is rendered by Javascript, so it will only have the full DOM if it's requested by something that executes Javascript. wp_remote_get() is not the tool for that job, you'd have to script visiting the page with a headless browser.

Can you explain how to do this in WP? Is this even possible in WP?

Not possible to do solely within WP, no. Your script to control the headless browser could exist within WP, but how to set a headless browser up is way off topic for this site. https://hacks.mozilla.org/2017/12/using-headless-mode-in-firefox/
